# Flutter - Hide FAB Button on swipe

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I have a Scaffold with a TabBarView and a FloatingActionButton. I want to hide this FAB whenever I swipe to the last tab. For that, I wrote the following code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget._tabBarController = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    widget._tabBarController.addListener(() {
      if (widget._tabBarController.index == 2) {
        setState(() => widget._visibleFab = false);
      } else {
        setState(() => widget._visibleFab = true);
      }
    });
  }
```

FAB Button withing the Scaffold

```
Visibility(
  visible: widget._visibleFab,
  child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
  elevation: .75,
  label: new Text("My Action Button",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    color: statusColor,
    letterSpacing: 0.2)),
  onPressed: () {

  },
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  icon: Icon(Icons.chat, color: statusColor),
  isExtended: true,
))
```

It works, but it takes about half second to hide it when I move to the last tab when I swipe. Unless I touch this last tab directly, without swipe the page, then it get hidden instantly.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't know man, but watch out with the ```widget._tabBarController.index == 2```. I had a lot of problems with something like that because with the last one it never gets to the end. Lets say you have 4 screens, it just gets to 3.99998. I don't know if its already fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `>1` instead of `==2` but didn't work. But I agree with you. I think the problem is this `if`.

Comment: For me it worked with >1.9, but it should work with >1 too.

Comment: just a thought. maybe try hiding the `FloatingActionButton` when `widget._tabBarController.indexIsChanging` is true. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html

Comment: I tried that too, nothing changed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your build method to return null if you don't want the Fab.

eg.

```
 floatingActionButton: _createFloatingActionButton(),
```

```
 Widget _createFloatingActionButton() {
    if (!_tfFabVisible) {
      return null;
    }
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _btnSubmitPressed,
```

Comment: Explain the reason for -1?

Comment: The problem isn't how to hide the FAB, but why it takes time to get hidden when I swipe the `TabBarView`. (Wasn't me who gave you -1, but this answer really doesn't help)

Comment: I presume that if you want to hide it then you don't want it to be used. If that is the case, and that is what I encountered, then the solution is to not show it in the first place. I presume that the reason for the delay is because Flutter first shows the widget and then hides it. So, that gets to my point, isn't it better not to show it if that is what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to hide it only in the 3rd tab, the 1st and 2nd tab must show this fab button.

Comment: I cannot see the problem. When you want the Fab visible, you do a setState() to either make the Fab Visible or not. My code will work for that, because setState() does a rebuild. It will show the Fab when you want to show it. setState() always does a build, so if the code returns a Fab, it will be visible, if it returns null, it will be invisible. Isn't that what you want? Try it, it doesn't take long.

Comment: It is working. The problem is that when I get to the last tab it takes time until the FAB get hidden. That's all. And then, when I move to the other tab it takes time until get visible again. It's ugly. Unless I touch the TabBar itself, then it works flaweslly.

Answer (score 0):

I end up deciding to use a `Scaffold` for each `TabBarView`. Now I can set up a `FloatActionButton` and a `BottomNavigatorBar` for each tab without hassle.